# Show spinning circle and text in an empty ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I am using a `ListView`. When the list is empty the spinning circle is showing which I want.
But I also want a text above/bellow that circle that displays a message eg. Loading
Adding the following only shows the text but not the spinning circle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Loading...."
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I have both?

**Note:** Not a `ProgressDialog`. The original ListView spinner + Text

**Update:**
If I add the following after the `TextView` the spinner breaks my list:

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2" >
    </ProgressBar>
```

Comment: Use  a linear layout (orientation vertiacal) and make progress bar and textview child of it.

Answer (score 0):

Make your TextView height and width wrap_content instead of match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just place textview and progressbar in a LinearLayout and the id of layout should be android:empty

```html
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Loading..."
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```